# How to calculate whether a $20\%$ chance for $10$ times return on investment is a reasonable investment?

Tags: probability

The investment is one year of the companies net profit. If a company were to reinvest their net profit back in their business they would see guaranteed 10% of net profit increase next year.

Time to see whether the investment is success or failure is 5 years, so the calculation should take into consideration the return of investment for those 10% over 5 years if the company decided to reinvest in their business.

Other $80\%$ chance of complete loss on investment.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $10\times0.2+0\times0.8=2>1$

Comment: It depends on your definition of reasonable. If you have $\$$100 and the minimum investment is $\$$100, then no, that is not a reasonable investment. If the minimum investment is considerably lower than $\$$100, then as J.W. Tanner showed, yes, that is a reasonable investment.

Comment: Note: According to the Kelly Criterion, the optimal investment would be $\dfrac{1}{9}$ of your total.

Comment: One criteria is the expected value. Here it is $10x\cdot 0.2-x\cdot 0.8-x=0.2x>0$. A positive expected value is the minimum requirement.

Comment: talk about changing gosls.